# Unable to fetch data using sql query - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in this form:

```
Year  Month Sales  US_CAN
2019   1     763    X5
2019   2     532    X9
2019   5     744    V6
2019   8     874    V1
2020   5     840    V8
2020   9     992    B7
2021   7     348    B2
```

So, I want to find the month, year for which Sales was highest and lowest, so I have written two queries here:

```
select month,year,max(Sales) from table_name;
select month,year,min(Sales) from table_name;
```

But this is giving me a invalid groupby expression error.

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you use.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to order by sales and choose the first row.  In Standard SQL for the maximum sales, for instance:

```
select t.*
from table_name t
order by sales desc
offset 0 row fetch first 1 row only;
```

Not all databases support the `fetch` clause; you would need to use the appropriate construct for your database.

Answer (score 0):

Use `RANK()` window function:

```
SELECT Year, Month, Sales, US_CAN
FROM (
  SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Sales) rn_min,
            RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Sales DESC) rn_max
  FROM table_name
) t
WHERE 1 IN (rn_min, rn_max)
```

For versions of MySql prior to 8.0:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE Sales = (SELECT MIN(Sales) FROM table_name)
   OR Sales = (SELECT MAX(Sales) FROM table_name)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1c40c58a01a4a1d88956079f8c908702).